# Setting default value for Rails select helper block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I set default value in Rails select helper block?

```
<div class="field">
  <label>Gender</label>
  <%= f.select :gender, [], { prompt: 'Select gender', selected: 'Female' }, { :class => 'ui selection dropdown' } do %>
    <% Subject.genders.keys.each do |c| %>
      <%= content_tag(:option, value: c, class: 'item') do %>
        <%= content_tag(:i, '', class: "#{c.downcase} icon") %>
        <%= content_tag(:span, c) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I tried setting it with `:selected` option but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if selected exist for f.select.

You can use `options_for_select(values, value_selected)`

Suggestion: 
You can create a file named app/helpers/select_helper.rb. In this file, you create a function like this:

```
def subject_genders_values
  Subject.genders.each do |c|
    [c.value, c.value]
  end
end
```

your function subject_genders_values can be re-used. And every time if you want a select box, you can create your function in this file.
Notice: add

```
include SelectHelper
```

in application_helper.rb

And your views:

```
<%= f.select :gender,options_for_select(subject_genders_values, 'Female') %>
```

The option Female will be selected if it's a part of the list.

Comment: Did you find the solution for your question? Is my answer useful for you ?